# How to click IE button with similar class names and attributes

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I'm currently stuck trying to click on buttons on a private website. The buttons I'm trying to click have the same attributes and I cannot distinguish which button I need to click.  Here are the three buttons I'm trying to click. As you can see, they are similar and except for the text on the button. How can I select for specific button and click it?

```
<button ng-repeat="punch in $ctrl.nextPunches" ng-disabled="punch.sendingPunch || $ctrl.sendingPunch" type="button" class="btn btn-default ng-binding ng-scope" ng-click="$ctrl.addPunch(punch)" style="">
                        <!-- ngIf: punch.sendingPunch -->
                        Check In
                    </button>
```

===========================================================================

```
<button ng-repeat="punch in $ctrl.nextPunches" ng-disabled="punch.sendingPunch || $ctrl.sendingPunch" type="button" class="btn btn-default ng-binding ng-scope" ng-click="$ctrl.addPunch(punch)">
                        <!-- ngIf: punch.sendingPunch -->
                        Start Meal
                    </button>
```

==========================================================================

```
<button ng-repeat="punch in $ctrl.nextPunches" ng-disabled="punch.sendingPunch || $ctrl.sendingPunch" type="button" class="btn btn-default ng-binding ng-scope" ng-click="$ctrl.addPunch(punch)">
                        <!-- ngIf: punch.sendingPunch -->
                        Check Out
                    </button>
```

I have tried using this:

```
Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")
    For Each HTMLbutton In HTMLButtons
       Debug.Print HTMLbutton.getAttribute("ng-click"), HTMLbutton.getAttribute("type"), HTMLbutton.getAttribute("ng-repeat"), HTMLbutton.getAttribute("ng-disabled")
    Next HTMLbutton
    HTMLButtons(2).Click
```

However, the buttons that show up on the immediate window is not helpful and it doesn't click any button when I use the .Click command. These buttons are under the UI element on the webpage. I'm not sure if that is helpful but I can definitely provide more of the webpage code if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: is it a public url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use document.getElementsByClassName method or document.getElementsByTagName method to get the button (it will return an array), then, loop through this array and distinguish them based on the **innerText** property. More detail, you could check [this article](http://automatetheweb.net/common-vba-methods-properties-web-automation/).

Besides, you could also add some custom attributes and set different value, then use it to distinguish them.